# Виджет для панели меню в QT

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Добрый день! Сейчас пишу интерфейс для программы и хочу узнать как в QT Designer сделать такую панельку, как на скриншоте:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Интересует панель Design, когда можно переключаться между разными опциями и менять содержимое окна, плюс если это QList то не понимаю откуда там заголовок, сам пишу на Python, буду благодарен за подсказку!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я для такой цели (обычно это окно настроек программы) использую `QListWidget` для списка страниц и `QStackedWidget` для смены интерфейса в правой части. Заголовок можно добавить как отдельно стоящий `QLabel`. К сигналу `QListWidget::currentRowChanged` присоединяем смену текущей страницы в `QStackedWidget`

Результат у меня выглядит примерно так:
[image: Окно настроек]

Answer (score 0):

Левая панель скорее всего `QTreeWidget`. Все настраивается по двойному клику.
Для переключения на дерево вешается обработчик `itemActivated`. По центру идет `QStackedWidget`. Он создает что-то типа вкладок `QTabWidget`, но без ярлыков